# Why aren't candidate vote totals accurate?

Tags: support, election

I was scrolling the [Primaries page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary), and clicked the downvote button on a post, yes?

[image: Single downvote]

Ok. This Primary entry had 0 votes, then I downvoted, so it has a score of -1. So far, so good.

I noticed If I click on the number, I can see how many votes it has because I have 1k+ rep.

[image: Full vote score]

`-14 + 6` is still `-8`, right? Almost all the other entries at [the Primary submissions page thingy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary) do the same sort of SE (common core) math.

Wat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a candidate is at a negative score, the score will display as your vote.

So, if you didn't vote, it will display as 0; if you downvoted, -1, and if you upvoted, 1.

The same question was [asked on Mother Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112127/180276)—[twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135576/180276)—presumably the reasoning is provided in the linked duplicate of the first question and the answer of the second question.

Comment: Is there some explanation of why this behavior was chosen? It is so heavily downvoted candidates don't feel as bad -- until they click?

Comment: @xnor I edited a MSE link into the answer (although the MSE post is somewhat unclear about it).

Comment: This isn't true, I see -6 for at least one candidate.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty unclear. It's marked as a dupe of a question that's asking something else.

Comment: @Morgan'Venti'Thrappuccino Did you expand the upvotes/downvotes? This only applies for the unexpanded view.

Comment: I see that without expanding.

Comment: @Morgan'Venti'Thrappuccino [status-norepro]. Perhaps refreshing the page will "fix" it (for certain definitions of fix).

Comment: @xnor I found [another MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135576/180276) that might be related (it describes slightly different behavior, but it could have been changed).