# Should we merge the voting tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have four tags about up/down-voting:

- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes)
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes)
- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)
- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes)

There's an argument to be made for keeping [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) separate since there's a bit of stuff about downvoting culture specifically which isn't necessarily related to the voting mechanism as a whole. However, browsing through all of its questions, I believe nothing would be lost from merging it into a tag with the rest of these.

How many of these should we merge? The existence of [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) and [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) seems like a mistake, but what about the other one, and which should we merge them into?

(Discussion started by caird coinheringaahing in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57981189))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Merge them all into [voting](/questions/tagged/voting)

[up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) and [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) shouldn't really exist in the first place tbh. They are both fully covered by [voting](/questions/tagged/voting), and a lot of the existing posts with those tags are also tagged with either [votes](/questions/tagged/votes)/[voting](/questions/tagged/voting)

As [discussed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57981189#57981189), [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) could also cover [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)/[reopening](/questions/tagged/reopening)/[vote-to-delete](/questions/tagged/vote-to-delete) (as well as [election votes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8812/why-arent-candidate-vote-totals-accurate)). This is far too broad for a single tag, especially when tags currently exist to further specify what the question is about. Since [my recent edits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing?tab=activity&sort=revisions), all questions under [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) discuss up/down votes and the questions that were tagged with [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) that didn't have been more appropriately tagged.

Therefore, I suggest that all 4 tags be either merged or synonymised under [voting](/questions/tagged/voting), and the tag wiki make note of the related [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)/[reopening](/questions/tagged/reopening)/[vote-to-delete](/questions/tagged/vote-to-delete) tags